# Windows Driver: prevent context switch while executing critical piece of code

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, multitasking, context-switch

I am currently working on a simple driver that is communicating over a serial port. This communication takes only very short time but it cannot be disturbed by anything until its over because there is a really short time-out. I already disabled interrupts with `cli` (and than re-enabling them with `sti`) but still it can be disturbed by switching between threads. Is there any way to disable context switching for a short time (on the current cpu) and than re-enabling it back ?

Comment: "I already disabled interrupts with `cli` (and than re-enabling them with `sti`) but still it can be disturbed by switching between threads." - With interrupts disabled the only way for a processor core to switch to another thread is **voluntary**  switching, that is by the function called from the current thread. If your code doesn't perform such calls, no one can switch the processor core to another thread.

Comment: Isnt it like that when interrupt flag is cleared only external interrupts (like from hardware) will be ignored ? I dont know how is windows switching between threads but couldnt another cpu (I use multicore cpu) force the core on which is code running to switch to another thread ? Thank you.

Comment: No one can **force** the processor core to execute anything. It is possible to send an interrupt (e.g. notification, or a timer) to the processor code, which causes *interrupt handler* to be executed on that core. And this interrupt handler could perform thread switching. But since you disable interrupts, this scenario cannot occur.